# Rename every files to a regex pattern found inside each file

Tags: regex, windows

Do you know a tool that can accomplish this? or some dirty batch command trick?

**Example:**
I have 1000 HTML files. Inside each HTML file, it contains the URL where the file was downloaded. Now, I want to rename each HTML file according to the captured URL found inside each file.

Comment: Could you please show some examples?

Comment: I've got a batch file, one my home machine (currently not at home, obviously) that renames files based on their extension. It might be similar to what you want (it uses a regular expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [FlashRenamer](http://www.rlvision.com/flashren/about.asp).

It's a shareware but fully functional for a period of X days.

Else, you can do this with batch commands.

It depends if you need this once, or many times.

Comment: I vote up first, and will check whether this software can do this.

Comment: @Astaroth : FlashRenamer can do this for you, it has a regex engine for renaming. I've already used it :)

Comment: @Astaroth : here is the guide, use the Capturing Patterns : http://www.rlvision.com/flashren/manual/appendix_regexp.html